# How To Easily Simulate A Large Number of Hosts?

Tags: networking

I'm working on writing a server type program. It is my first time doing stuff with concurrency and I am wanting to test it against a large number of hosts. I'd like to test 2000+ hosts at a time. I need to open a socket connection to each of these clients from my server.

Is there anyway to do this, easily? I've thought about trying to create 2k+ VMs on my machine and some friends but that seems arduous. Is there a scriptable way to do this? Is there some service I can pay? Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185), [code fragments](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), services, etc.

Comment: You could [edit] your question to make it clear that you *are* asking for software. If you do that, please be clear on your requirements - OS, budget, etc.